# Combine two density plots in R into one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, density-plot

I want to combine two separate density plots I created in Rstudio into one plot that displays both.

I used the following code to create the two separate density plots:

```
1 # create density plot for total sales
dens_plot_sales <- final_data %>%
drop_na(tot_sales, firm_size) %>%
ggplot()+
geom_density(aes(x = tot_sales, colour = firm_size)) +
labs(title = "Density plot of total sales across firm size levels", 
x = "Total sales", y = "Density", col= "Firm size") +
theme_classic()

2 # create density plot for total costs
dens_plot_costs <- final_data %>%
drop_na(tot_costs, firm_size) %>%
ggplot()+
geom_density(aes(x = tot_costs, colour = firm_size)) +
labs(title = "Density plot of total costs across firm size levels", 
x = "Total costs", y = "Density", col= "Firm size") +
theme_classic()
```

How to I combine plot 1 [(dens_plot_sales)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJsDM.png) and plot 2 ([dens_plot_costs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGkUv.png)) into one?
(see the plots attached for reference)

Thanks!

Comment: be aware that ggplot will determine the axis based on the first graph in the code. It will 'stick' the second one over the first one. If the scales are widely different (doesn't seem to be the case here) the result will look off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# create density plot for total sales and costs
dens_plot_sales <- final_data %>%
drop_na(tot_sales, firm_size) %>%
ggplot()+
geom_density(aes(x = tot_sales, colour = firm_size)) +
geom_density(aes(x = tot_costs, colour = firm_size)) + # It's that simple
labs(title = "Density plot of total sales and costs across firm size levels", 
x = "Total sales/costs ($)", y = "Density", col= "Firm size") +
theme_classic()
```

I can't test it fully without knowing what `final_data` is, but this should work

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks! (final_data is the data table/set with all my relevant variables and observation values)

Although the combined graph is displayed a bit strange now, so I might drop the firm size levels or keep them separate. Thanks though!